# What if there were a song that (is/were) about cars?

Tags: grammar, subjunctive-mood

I've been wondering about this sentence:

> What if there were a song that is about cars?

I know that the first verb there should be in the subjunctive (were) because it follows the word "if", but what about the second verb? Should that also be "were"?

In addition, can you just say "a song about cars", or does that need a linking verb?

Comment: No, it doesn't need to use the so-called "subjunctive" *were*.

Comment: "What if there were a song about cars" would be far more natural.

Answer (score 0):

You are talking about a hypothetical universe.  This is identified by 'if', and it is also identified by 'were' (the wrong plurality for a singular song in our universe).  You should use 'was about cars', not 'were' or 'is'.  PS: 'That' is optional in your sentence, and whenever the sub-subject is traced (blank).